# ¿Como hacer un input file obligatorio?

Tags: javascript, html

Cordial Saludo,

Espero me puedan ayudar, lo que deseo hacer es poner obligatorio un input de tipo "file".

```
<form method="POST"  id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="1" name="1" class="form-control-file">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviardoc" value="Enviar Documentos">
</form>
```

Ya que lo capturo y lo envío mediante AJAX, Pero deseo que sea obligatorio.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
                      $("#frm_contact").on("submit", function(e){
                          e.preventDefault();
                          var f = $(this);
                          var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frm_contact"));

                          $.ajax({
                              url: "DocumentosApro.php",
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: "html",
                              data: formData,datos,
                              cache: false,
                              contentType: false,
                              processData: false
                          })
                              .done(function(res){
                                  alert(res);
                                  location.reload();

                              });
                      });

                    }); 
</script>
```

Cabe resaltar que el archivo se envia bien, este o no cargado un archivo, el hace la funcion, pero quiero que sea obligatorio..

Gracias

Comment: ¿Has probado añadiéndole un required al input? Los type="file" los aceptan también: **<input type="file" id="1" name="1" class="form-control-file" required>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional, es cierto que puedes agregar el atributo de `HTML required`, pero si quieres un poco más de seguridad puedes validar desde Javascript, intenta esto.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#frm_contact").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    /*Con el id del input tipo file le indicas que lea la longitud o cantidad de 
      archivos que se seleccionaron*/
    var vidFileLength = $("#uploadFile")[0].files.length;

    /*Aquí validas si no han seleccionado archivos mandas una alerta y se detiene el 
     script*/
    if (vidFileLength === 0) {
      alert("No hay archivos, para enviar.");
     return false;
    }
    var f = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frm_contact"));

    $.ajax({
        url: "DocumentosApro.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: formData,
        datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      })
      .done(function(res) {
        alert(res);
        location.reload();

      });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="POST" id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" id="1" name="1" class="form-control-file">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviardoc" value="Enviar Documentos">
</form>
```

De igual forma siempre es importante realizar la validación desde el lado del servidor.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto un pequeño fragmento de HTML para que vea como aplicar lo que comentas, pero antes un poco de teoría:

- Para lograr lo que necesitas, el atributo **requerido** es un
  atributo **booleano** que resuelve tu problema.
  Cuando este presente, especifica que se debe completar un campo de
  entrada antes de enviar el formulario.
  Considera lo siguiente: Funciona con los siguientes tipos de entrada:
  texto, búsqueda, url, teléfono, correo electrónico, contraseña,
  selectores de fecha, número, casilla de verificación, radio y
  archivo.

Al a la etiqueta del input, le agregas el atributo **required** que describí anteriormente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Además, es recomendado que las validaciones las realices en tu JS o JQuery por seguridad, te comparto un ejemplo de su aplicación:

```js
function Jq(){
  console.log();
    if ($('#txtrut').val() == "") {
        alert('¡Vacío!');
        return false;
    }else{
      alert('¡Completo!');
      
    }
};

function Js(){
 valor = document.getElementById("txtrut1").value;
 if( valor != "" ) {
  alert('¡Completo!');
 }else{
   alert('¡Vacío!');
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Validación con Libreria JQuery --> 
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label>Validación con JQuery</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtrut" >
<button onclick="Jq();">Validate</button>

<!-- Validacion con javascript -->
<br>
<label>Validación con Javascript</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtrut1" >
<button onclick="Js();">Validate</button>
```

Espero os ayude,

Suerte...

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Deberías añadir algo más de información: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿qué diferencia hay con el código de la pregunta? ¿por qué resolvería el problema? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.